# disabling def from acting on other parts of documents

Tags: tables, macros

I use a simple command to stretch rows of a table in my document. (It is Table 1.2)

The command is shown below

```
{\def\arraystretch{1.65}\tabcolsep=8pt
```

But what happen is, this stretches all other tables in my document.

Is there any way to make this command function only on Table 1.2 and not to other tables?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to limit the scope of the redefinitions of `\arraystretch` and `\tabcolsep`.

Since the scope is supposed to be a single `table` environment, you may achieve your objective by inserting the instructions immediately after the relevant `\begin{table}` instruction; the scope of the redefinitions ends when `\end{table}` is encountered.

```
....
\begin{table} % Table 1.2
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.65}  % modify two important parameters
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
... % remainder of material for Table 1.2
\end{table}
```

---

For completeness, here's a full, compilable example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report} % need a document class with chapter-level sectioning
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example
\setcounter{table}{1}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.65}
\setlength\tabcolsep{8pt}
\caption{Stretched parameters}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
\hline
a & b\\
c & d\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!] % "[h!]" just for this example
\caption{Default parameters}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|cc|}
\hline
a & b\\
c & d\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```